# Not receiving the push notification in android

Tags: android, push-notification, pushwoosh

Actually am new to push notification. I followed the below link: [pushwoosh](https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android/native-android-sdk-integration/)

and am getting the resgitration success message in logcat

> 08-26 15:03:54.917: W/Pushwoosh: Request manager(15266):
>   PushWooshResult:
>   {"status_code":200,"status_message":"OK","response":null}

I am not getting any notification, but it is reported that the notification is send in pushwoosh.

Comment: did u setup ur google gcm acount?

Comment: @Deb:: yes I created an api key in google console

Comment: Solved device id is mismatched. So only i din receive the notification after correcting it am getting the notification.

Comment: What is the device ID, and how did you correct it @Jeevanandhan ?!

Comment: @AmrBarakat: I fixed it a long back. device id should be the android mobile device's unique id.